# Backup specific keys to google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, key-value

I want to backup specific key/value to the google drive, then when the user changes his phone or factory reset his phone then installs my app while he have the same google account on his phone I want to restore these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store key/value pairs directly to Drive (like you do with shared preferences on Android) but you can use Drive API to create and maintain a file containing your key/value pairs.
You can follow this guide to use Drive API with Java:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java

Comment: if not drive, where can i save a key/value in a way that it's linked to the gmail account on this device?

Comment: Please take a look at this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup.html